# Replace ending of string in C using backwards for loop

Tags: c, string, replace

I am trying to replace the last part of a string using a for backward for loop iterating for every element of the original string and assigning the first (last elements because I am iterating backwards in the for loop) elements to the string `scl = "SCL_10m.tif"`, and the rest when the counter hits lower than 15, then get all the characters from the string `string`, and assign them to the `newString`.
However at the end the result is:

```
The old string was: S2_2018_08_09_B02_10m.tif
The new string is S2_2018_08_09_B0old string:
```

Which is different from my expected result:

```
The new string is S2_2018_08_09_SCL_10m.tif
```

I don't know what that happened. It supposed to iterate over all the elements of the `newString` Since it is the same size as the original string. I checked some replace string functions in C, but I wanted to implement something that helps me fast at this particular replace substring in String problem.

Dealing with String in C is very complicated and I am still learning some theory about it, such as: the null Byte and so on. Coming from JavaScript, Python, and Ruby where more of this functions are already implemented in some standard library, I find very hard and at the same time helpful to get the idea of how to implement such algorithms from scratch to deal with specific problems in my code. 
I appreciate any idea or hint about what is happening in the code below:

```
/******************************************************************************

                    Replace last 11 characters in a longer string
                    by the values of a smaller (11-char long) string.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *string;
    string =  "S2_2018_08_09_B02_10m.tif";
    char *scl; 
    scl =  "SCL_10m.tif";
    int length = 0;
    int length_scl = 0;
    length_scl = strlen(scl);
    length = strlen(string);
    char newstring[length];
    int i;
    int cntr = length;
    for (i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(cntr > 15){
            newstring[i] = scl[i];
            cntr--;
        }
        else if(cntr <= 15)
        {
            newstring[i] = string[i];
        }


    }
    printf("The old string was: %s\n", string);
    printf("The new string is %s:\n", newstring);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where you get the number 15 from. Regardless: you can use `strncpy` to copy parts of a string without the need of a loop. The main issue I see is that you don't dynamically allocate memory for `newstring`, which you should. Normally you would use `malloc`, but in this case you can just use `strdup(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *func1(char *new, const char *src, const char *repl)
{
    size_t src_len, repl_len;

    if(src && repl)
    {
        src_len = strlen(src);
        repl_len = strlen(repl);
        if(src_len >= repl_len)
        {
            new[src_len] = 0;
            while(repl_len)
            {
                new[--src_len] = repl[--repl_len];
            }
            if(src_len)
            {
                while(--src_len)
                {
                    new[src_len] = src[src_len];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new;
}

char *func2(char *new, const char *src, const char *repl, size_t nchars)
{
    //last nchars only (inluding the nul char)
    size_t src_len, repl_len;

    if(new &&src && repl)
    {
        new[--nchars] = 0;
        src_len = strlen(src);
        repl_len = strlen(repl);
        if(src_len >= repl_len)
        {
            while(repl_len && nchars)
            {
                new[--nchars] = repl[--repl_len];
                --src_len;
            }
            if(src_len && nchars)
            {
                while(--src_len && --nchars)
                {
                    new[nchars] = src[src_len];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new;
}

int main()
{
    char *string =  "S2_2018_08_09_B02_10m.tif";
    char *repl =  "SCL_10m.tif";
    char new[256];
    printf("func1 - new = \"%s\", src = \"%s\", repl = \"%s\"\n", func1(new, string, repl), string, repl);
    printf("func2 - new = \"%s\", src = \"%s\", repl = \"%s\"\n", func2(new, string, repl, 15), string, repl); 
    printf("func2 - new = \"%s\", src = \"%s\", repl = \"%s\"\n", func2(new, string, "123456789_SCL_10m.tif", 15), string, repl); 
    return 0;
}
```